# Creating inner components inside a panel

Tags: javascript, extjs, panel, containers

I have the working code here: to create two different panels inside of a container:

```
Ext.application({
    requires: ['Ext.container.Viewport'],
    name: 'AM',

    appFolder: 'app',

    controllers: [
        'Users'
    ],

      launch: function() {
        Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            width: 900,
            height: 600,
            title: 'The Panel',
            layout: { 
            type: 'hbox'

            },
            items: [
                { xtype: 'panel', padding: 5, height: 500, width: '35%' },
                { xtype: 'userlist', padding: 5, height: 500, width: '65%' },
            ],
            listeners: {
                render: function() {
                  console.log('The Panel was rendered');
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

What I want to do is be able to put different components inside of the left panel (i.e. comboboxes, inputboxes, etc.). How can I do this and what would be the best practice to create these components? (Should everything go in app.js?)

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the `items` config property.  Use this as an array to add child components:

```
{
    xtype: 'panel',
    items: [
        { xtype: 'combo' }
    ]
}
```

You will want to take a look at the docs for this, it is pretty fundamental info that you will need to know if you plan to use the ExtJS framework much: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/guide/components

Comment: I thought to use that, I just didn't have the right syntax down (new to extjs, so I appreciate it).

Comment: But should every single component in my entire application be put into app.js? That doesn't seem like a good idea.

Comment: Definitely not.  You really should start with the "Getting started" guide that Sencha provides here: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/guide/getting_started  Then work your way through all of those guides.  You will end up with a file structure similar to any OOP package system.